# Constructing tangent without using centre.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

In the website [Cbse Guess](https://www.cbseguess.com) the following construction is given for constructing tangent without using the centre.
[image]
What is the proof of this construction?

Comment: The inscribed angles at P and R subtend the same arc PQ.

Answer (score 1):

Place $R'$ so that $QR'$ is parallel to the tangent. Now we get that $\angle R'PY = \angle PR'Q$, where $Y$ is on the tangent, on the opposite side of $P$ from $X$. Also, because of the symmetry, $\angle R'PY = \angle QPX$. Finally, note that no matter where we place $R$, as long as it's on the correct arc, we have $\angle PRQ = \angle PR'Q$. Stringing all these equalities together, we end up with $\angle PRQ = \angle QPX$.

Comment: sir how do we prove it is the tangent?

Comment: @RamKeswani Technically, I have proven that if the tangent is already there, then the angles will be equal. Surely you can see that this means that if the angles are equal then you have found the tangent.

Comment: sir last question, how is angle R' PY = angle QPX? i do not get 'by symmetry' .thank you

Comment: @RamKeswani If you draw the diameter through $P$, then it's normal to the tangent, and therefore normal to $QR'$, so the entire figure is symmetric around that line. That specifically means that done pairs of angles, like that one, are equal.